# Android don't detect the loss of focus of a web page when using multi-window

Tags: javascript, android, web

I need to monitor that users viewing my site have the page in the foreground and in focus.

The codes (also partially described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70805346/detecting-whether-the-web-page-is-in-focus-in-a-mobile-environment-android) ) work correctly in the Desktop environment, however if the user is using Android's multi-window mode then I cannot determine if my site is still in focus or if the user is interacting with another application.

What can I do?

Example of Android's multi-window feature:

[image: Android multi window]